# Computing $\int \frac{dx}{(x-1)\sqrt{2x^2-2x+1}}$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

I need to compute the following integral:  $$\int \frac{dx}{(x-1)\sqrt{2x^2-2x+1}}$$

**My try:**

I saw that the derivative of $\sqrt{2x^2-2x+1}$ is $\frac{2 x - 1}{\sqrt{2 x^2 - 2 x + 1}}$, so I used $u=\sqrt{2x^2-2x+1}$, $du=\frac{2 x - 1}{\sqrt{2 x^2 - 2 x + 1}} dx$. Then the integral is:  $$\int \frac{du}{(x-1)(2x-1)} = \int \frac{du}{2x^2-3x+1} $$

So my try doesn't work (I thought I would get $u^2$ or something like that in the denominator, but I'm off by $x$)

Any hints are appreciated.

Comment: Actually, your attempt works. You can continue by using Partial Fractions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $2x^2-2x+1=\dfrac{(2x-1)^2+1^2}2$

using [Trigonometric substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_substitution), $2x-1=\tan t$  where $-\dfrac\pi2\le t\le\dfrac\pi2$

$$\int\dfrac{dx}{(x-1)\sqrt{2x^2-2x+1}}=\sqrt2\int\dfrac{\sec^2t\ dt}{(\tan t-1)\sec t}=\sqrt2\int\dfrac{dt}{\sin t-\cos t} =\int\dfrac{dt}{\sin\left(t-\dfrac\pi4\right)}$$

Answer (score 3):

Substitute $x=\frac y{1+y}$
$$\int \frac{dx}{(x-1)\sqrt{2x^2-2x+1}}
=- \int \frac1{\sqrt{1+y^2}}dy=-\sinh^{-1}y
$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Substitute $$\sqrt{2x^2-2x+1}=\sqrt{2}x+t$$ the so called Euler substitution.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: can also take substitution as
Let $$(x-1)=\frac{1}{t}$$
Integration will get reduced to form $$\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{at^2+bt+c}}$$

Answer (score 0):

I would go this way.
\begin{eqnarray}
\mathcal I &=& \int \frac1{(x-1)\sqrt{2x^2-2x+1}}dx=\\
&=&\frac1{\sqrt 2}\int\frac1{(x-1)\sqrt{\left(x-\frac12\right)^2+\frac14}}dx.
\end{eqnarray}
Then substitute $x-\frac12 = \frac12 t$, to get
\begin{eqnarray}
\mathcal I &=& \frac1{2\sqrt 2}\int\frac{1}{\left(\frac{t}2-\frac12\right)\sqrt{\frac{t^2}4+\frac14}}dt=\\
&=&\sqrt 2\int \frac{1}{(t-1)\sqrt{t^2+1}}dt.
\end{eqnarray}